# Totally ignore Visual Studio errors and force compile

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to compile a game dll, The game runs on DLL's and I've extracted my DLL. Added the code then I plan on recompiling it. Except there is a small problem, as the game heavily relies on the Unity engine its pretty impossible to compile the game back up as Visual Studio gives me a staggering 15000 errors from things it cant call.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Yeah, look at what the errors are trying to tell you, then fix the errors. These aren't "Visual Studio Errors" - they're compiler errors, and the compiler can't produce binary when there are errors.

Comment: You can compile through warnings. If you have an error your code can't compile because it isn't valid C# and the compiler only knows how to convert valid C# to IL.

Answer (score 7):

Plain and simple, you can't. Compiler error CANNOT be ignored, they occur because the compiler found something that completely impedes further processing and the correct generation of the binary. The only way to make it possible to compile is to fix all syntax errors, data types mismatches, etc, and feed the appropriate compile-time dependencies so it can link to whatever is required.

Now to your particular case. You say the game depends on Unity. To compile then, Unity is 100% required, period, otherwise you have to remove it and rewrite the code accordingly to eliminate the dependency (which can be an enormous task if you're not familiar with the code and libraries). But, I ask, does the game runs at all, before messing with this DLL? If so, the required binaries should be already installed on your system. The program folder most likely will contain the dependencies, and you can point the project references to those or (preferably) copy them to your project source and use those to compile.

You can also simply go search and download the library right away, so you can fulfill any compile-time requirements. This is pretty much the standard way most people develop when it comes to 3rd party code I suppose.